# Write a statement that increases numPeople by 5. If numPeople is initially 10, then numPeople becomes 15

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
   int numPeople = 0;

   numPeople = 10;
   /* Your solution goes here  */

      if (numPeople = 10)
         numPeople + 5;


   printf("There are %d people.\n", numPeople);

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: any idea why this wont run?

Comment: Because you are assigning not comparing

Comment: `if (numPeople ==10)
         numPeople += 5;`

Comment: You don't even need the condition. Just say `numPeople += 5;`.

Comment: What do you expect this `numPeople + 5;` to do?

Comment: add 5 to the numPeople? @alk

Comment: @user3349525: ... and does not store the result anywhere. So the whole line is NOOP.

Answer (score 1):

You do a assignment in your if statement! So change it to this:

```
if (numPeople == 10) 
            //^^ See here 2x '=' is a comparison and 2x '=' is a assignment
```

Also you forgot the assign operator here:

```
numPeople + 5;
```

Change it to:

```
numPeople += 5;  //Same as numPeople = numPeople + 5;
```

FYI:

You can initialize your variable with 10 like:

```
int numPeople = 10;
```

Also if you change your condition to this:

```
if (10 == numPeople)
```

It's a bit more save, because if you now make a typo and write = you will get a error and see it! The other way around it will just assign the value to the variable and it's hard to stop that then.

Comment: And also, the logic is completely wrong, aka not what's in the assignment.

Comment: @Deduplicator Updated my answer! (@DownVoter please explain what's so bad at my answer?)

Comment: I would still prefer a statement about the assignment being an *unconditional* increment (even if a specific testcase was given as an example). Also, personally I detest Yoda-conditions, any worthwhile compiler (or lint) will warn if asked anyway.

Answer (score 1):

> Write a statement that increases numPeople by 5.

```
numPeople += 5;
```

> If numPeople is initially 10, then numPeople becomes 15.

Correct. Increasing 10 by 5 yields 15. The statement above satisfies this test-case.

Comment: I think the OP meant when `numPeople != 10` it shall not be increased, so it was always being `15` after the condition obviously.

Comment: @iharob There's nothing in their post that suggests that, if you consider punctuation.

Comment: _If numPeople is initially 10, then numPeople becomes 15_? how would a programmer read this?

Comment: @iharob A programmer would read it as a test-case or example that is true if the requirements are satisfied . If `numPeople` is initially 42, it becomes 47. And so on.

Comment: I don't think that a so obvious consequence of adding 5 to a number would be expressed in the question that way.

Comment: @iharob Well, it seems completely obvious to me. It certainly doesn't say "Write a statement that increases numPeople by 5 only if `numPeople` has the value 10".

Answer (score -1):

This is the assignment operator

```
if (numPeople = 10)
```

you need the comparison operator `==`

```
if (numPeople == 10)
```

since the value of an assignment can be used as a condition, thus the code compiled correctly if you want to prevent such problem try this way

```
if (10 == numPeople)
```

if you erroneously use the assignment operator in this case, the code will not compile.

As it was, when reaching the `if` line, you was assigning `10` to `numPeople` and the next expression was doing nothing, so the value of `numPeople` was always `10`.

To increment `numPeople` by 5 you need the `+=` operator, or the following expression which is very easy to understand

```
numPeople = numPeople + 5;
```

so you assign to `numPeople` it's current value +5, you could also write this using the folloing

```
numPeople += 5;
```

Comment: Yes but A) that isn't the only error, B) the condition isn't needed.